# How to undo "git push --mirror"?

Tags: git, github

On a git/github project I am working on a branch. Upon a push, it said the following:

```
git push
To git@github.com:...
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:...'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried to fix this problem and upon Googleing I came up with this line:

```
git push --mirror
```

I issued the following command and now it seems that I have deleted a lot of branches from the server.

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:...
 - [deleted]         develop
 + 797beee...bafbc50 master -> master (forced update)
 - [deleted]         milestone
 - [deleted]         robot
 - [deleted]         strategy
 * [new branch]      origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD
 * [new branch]      origin/develop -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      origin/master -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      origin/milestone -> origin/milestone
 * [new branch]      origin/robot -> origin/robot
 * [new branch]      origin/robot_simulator -> origin/robot_simulator
 * [new branch]      origin/strategy -> origin/strategy
 * [new branch]      origin/vision -> origin/vision
```

**Can you tell me what has happened and how can I undo the change I made?** (in case I deleted those branches)

Comment: You know, if you look at `git push --help` (which is just `man git-push`), in the section it mentions, it explains about the "problem", and describes the primary ways to deal with it...

Comment: This question deserves points, but the author deserves punishment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You pushed to the default push target, git@github.com. This means, that git@github.com was a remote in you source repo.

That implies, that the refs deleted from the server would still be in the remote locally after the push. **Do not update the remotes** (!).

Verify this by doing

```
git branch -a
```

on the side you *pushed* from (local).

It will probably show the refs that were deleted from the remote server.

[to be continued]

You could do something like:

```
for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin | while read sha type name
do 
    git branch "rescue_$(basename "$name")" "$sha"
done
```

to recover the branches locally. They will be named prefixed with `rescue_` just as a precaution (in case you get funny or conflicting ref names).

**Replace `origin` with the name of your remote**

---

### Test script

In case you want to test the procedure in a controlled environment, here is my approach condensed to minimum steps (execute in an empty dir, e.g. /tmp/work)

```
git init A; (cd A; touch test; git add test; git commit -m initial; git branch test1; git branch test2; git branch test3)
git clone A B
(cd B; git push --mirror origin; git branch -a)
cd A
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin | while read sha type name; do git branch "rescue_$(basename "$name")" "$sha"; done
git branch -a
```

Note how in this version, I cd into `A` - which would be your github repo. You could `git clone --mirror git@github.com:... local_rescue` in order to get a suitable local version of that.

**I recommend you play around getting to terms with the procedure before trying it out**. It never hurts to backup your repositories along the way.

Comment: `git push --mirror` cleans up the remote branches. There won't be anything in `refs/remotes/origin` that's not on the remote. It's a good suggestion, and it'd be nice if it worked, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @Jefromi: you didn't just test that, because I _did_. git version 1.7.4.1

Comment: Er, so did I... hrm. I created a toy repo with two branches, made a bare clone, added the bare clone as a remote in the original, deleted one of the branches, did a mirror push, and the branch is gone from refs/remotes and logs/refs/remotes. Git version 1.7.7.3. Let's hope that either I somehow botched it, or the OP has your version.

Comment: Funny, could it be that you remotes wasn't up-to-date before you pushed? I pushed from a single repo that just cloned a single branch from a 4-branch repo. After `git push --mirror origin` the clone still contained the other branch refs in remotes/origin/ (as did the push target, since it became a mirror).

Comment: Never mind, I did botch it, oops. This is good. (You already had my +1.) Funny how cleaning up code makes you immediately notice the mistake!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7439/discussion-between-sehe-and-jefromi)

Comment: It works for me ! Thanks a lot ! You made and save my day.

Answer (score 4):

You were in a situation like this:

```
- x - A - B - C (origin/master)
   \
    D - E - F (master)
```

You wanted to do one of two things, both of which are described in the documentation that Git suggested you read:

- Pull, then push, giving you this:

  ```
  - x - A - B - C
     \           \
      D - E - F - M (master, origin/master)
  ```
- Force push (`git push --force`), giving you this:

  ```
  - x - D - E - F (master, origin/master)
  ```

Instead, with `git push --mirror` you basically did the equivalent of force-pushing everything, making the remote repository into a mirror of your local one. This means, just like it reported, deleting everything on the remote that wasn't in your repository.

Edit: sehe's answer describes how to recover. If you *have* run `git remote update`, which would have deleted the remote branches it uses to recover from, then the following could be useful. Otherwise, you're all set.

Your best bet is to find someone else who has cloned from the remote repository (or if you're lucky, a separate clone that you'd made), tell them **not to pull/fetch/remote update**, and follow sehe's instructions from that repo.

Failing that, recovering is going to be really tricky. If you've interacted with any of the remote branches recently, it's possible there will be traces in `HEAD`'s reflog:

```
git reflog show
```

Otherwise, if the deleted refs refer to commits which are ancestors of any remaining branches, you can maybe recreate them quickly. If they refer to things which *aren't* ancestors of remaining branches, you can find dangling commits:

```
git fsck
```

and perhaps figure out which ones had branches pointed to them.

Comment: I have an other computer where 'git branch -a' still lists all the deleted branches. What would be the best way to recover from it?

Comment: @zsero: Look at sehe's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run

```
git branch -a
```

[image]
Then you can see all the deleted branches there.

Afterwards checkout to each entry and create a new branch from it.

Like

```
git checkout remotes/origin/endpoint
git checkout -b res_endpoint
```

Note: do it for all the entries