# Keeping tags in target repository during git mirror

Tags: git, github

We're using git's mirror functionality to mirror an OSS repository into our own git mirror on github.  We then tag the sha revisions we deploy in our private mirror so that we can correlate the source to the release.  Unfortunately, when the mirror sync runs, it removes the tags in the target mirror b/c they don't exist in the source mirror.  Is there any way to mirror and retain the tags on the target repo?

Here's how we're syncing in our sync script.

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/usergrid/usergrid.git usergrid_mirror
cd usergrid_mirror
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/mycompany/usergrid.git
git push --mirror
```

When I execute the "push --mirror" my tags in the mycompany/usergrid.git get deleted.

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Can you execute `git tag` after the `cd usergrid_mirror` ? If there is an output (tags), try `git push --mirror --tags` in place of the last command.

Answer (score 0):

As in "[How to undo “`git push --mirror`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9184625/6309)", you could look in the reflog and see if you can restore the tags that way.

But a more sensible solution going foward would be to:

- use `git push --mirror` only for the initialization
- don't make any commits on the branches common with the OSS repo, only on new private branches
- update your mirror with a `git push --all` everytime you want to update your mirror.