# Tag for entire AOSP repository for a local git server setup

Tags: android, git, android-source, gerrit, git-tag

I setup a AOSP code for my local git server with the following steps,

**Mirror code on server :**

mkdir AOSP_MIRROR

cd AOSP_MIRROR

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-1.6_r1.2 --mirror

repo sync

/* Git daemon setup */

git daemon --port=9418 --export-all --reuseaddr --base-path=.

**On client side :**

Sync the code using below command:

repo init –u git:///platform/manifest -b android-1.6_r1.2

Repo sync –j16

**My requirment is**

1. i want to create a git tag for entire AOSP repository projects, please share the command and from which machine ( Server or client ) i need to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repo forall -c`  command to actually run commands in each project. This would have to be done on the server I believe.

Ref:

1. https://git-repo.info/en/docs/multi-repos/git-repo-forall/
2. [Keeping tags in target repository during git mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446177/keeping-tags-in-target-repository-during-git-mirror)